# What is the best way to spawn a Thread with an infinite loop in Java 8?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method that needs to be called every n seconds. In the old days of Java, I would do something like this:

```
Runnable task = () -> {

  while (!updater.isInterrupted()) {
       //some Task
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
   }
};
Thread updater = new Thread(task);
updater.start();
```

}

But this is obviously a bad idea. If I want to stop the Thread, I need to call updater.interrupt() and rely on exception handling which is actually not made for this stuff.

So I guess there's some fancy "new" Java8 way of doing this.I've seen this:

```
public class TestSchedularService {
 long sleep = 500;

 @Test
 public void testLoop2() throws Exception {
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ScheduledFuture future = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new PollingService(), 0, sleep,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
Thread.sleep(2 * sleep);
future.cancel(false);
executor.shutdown();
 }
}

class PollingService implements Runnable {
 private int count = 0;
public void run() {
System.out.println("iteration :" + (count++));
 }
}
```

but it seems like it's creating an instance of PollingService on every call which seems to be bad. So what's the most efficient and "up to date" way of calling a method every n seconds?

Comment: btw this is not new in Java 8 but was introduced in Java 7

Comment: **Warning:** All code inside the `run` method should be wrapped in a `try`-`catch`. If an exception floats up from your code and reaches the `ScheduledExecutorService` that executor silently stops, cancelling all future scheduled runs. This fact is buried in the class doc somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ScheduledExecutorService` is correct way. It doesn't create new instance of `PollingService`, you create it and the executor calls `run` on the same instance all the time until you cancel the `Future`.